# How to install FFMPEG on Ubuntu aarch64

Tags: ffmpeg, arm

I need to install `ffmpeg` on Ubuntu aarch64 Architecture. I searched the web but all the guides are about how to install `ffmpeg` on other Ubuntu distros.

Comment: One possibility is to upgrade to Ubuntu 15.xx as @incBrain noted the most recent Ubuntu versions include ARM64 binaries as noted [here for 15.04](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg/7:2.5.4-1) and [here for 15.10](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg/7:2.7.6-0ubuntu0.15.10.1).

Answer (score 2):

I think if you are using Ubuntu 15.XX you can simply run:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

if you are on the lower Ubuntu version you can just simply download static builds from [here](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/). Or type this in the terminal:

```
wget http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz
tar xf ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz
cd ffmpeg-3.0-64bit-static/
```

Static build of ffmpeg `./ffmpeg` will be inside this folder. You can also move it to /usr/local/bin to be able to run it from everywhere.

Comment: My distro is 14.04 but it is aarch64.   I tried your solution but i get this error   : bash: /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Comment: @Medow ah, I'm sorry didn't read carefully enough, so it's kind of ARM thing? Did you also try to compile ffmpeg?

Comment: No problem , And yes i did tried to compile it from source, but no success.

Comment: @Medow I can not find static builds for ARM. But it should be possible to compile it. What was the problem while you was trying to compile it?